# Displaying the content of a DIV on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `HTML` form. On submission the form `POST` values to page.php. The view then navigates to `page.php` and displays a success message. I want to prevent the user from navigating to `page.php`, and display `<div id="first">`

In other words, what i want to do is a reset. (Displaying `<div id="first">` after user clicks the Done button)

```
    <form action="page.php" method="post">
    <div id="first" class="m span3">
      THIS DIV CONTAINS FEW TEXT BOXES
    </div>
<div id="second" class="m2 span3">
      THIS DIV CONTAINS FEW TEXT BOXES AND COMBOBOXES
    </div>
<div id="last" class="m3 span3">
      THIS DIV CONTAINS FEW TEXT BOXES
    </div>
    </form>
```

Once the user clicks the DOne button the following function gets fired

```
function onComplete() {


        $('form').submit();
        alert("clicked");


}
```

Comment: where is the done button ? also, is the div hidden initially ?

Comment: There's a button in the form, when the user clicks on it the form will get submitted (`onComplete()` gets executed). The Div is not hidden initially. THis is a wizard application, where each div will be displayed. Now, once the form gets submitted i want to show the first div.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to post data to **main.php** without redirecting the page I recommend you to use Ajax. this is a simple code but can give you an idea to build your application :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function complete() {
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    data  : "text="+$("#"+textbox_1).value,
    url : "page.php",
    success : function(response){
        alert("Done!");
    }
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="page.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="textbox_1">   
<button onclick="complete()">submit</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and use $_POST['text'] in page.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('first').show();
}
```

Try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can ad a value to the url and use that one value to call the div. 
eg:

```
 <form action="page.php?action=formSent" method="post">
  // form data  
 </form>
```

then use some php to get the action call and use it to show the div:

```
 <?php
     if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "formSent" ){         
         <div id="first">
             div content
         </div>
     } 
 ?>
```

you can place the php code above of the form